# Would humans win a war against sapient trucks?

Tags: internal-consistency, slavery, extinction

Stephen King's short story "Trucks", which can be read almost in its entirety [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=1-nnlVg1busC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false), depicts the beginning a world where trucks have been given sapience by an unknown force. Here's what we know:

- Only vehicles considered "trucks" (semitrailers, pickup trucks, monster trucks, and the like) are affected, and we know some construction equipment is affected through the appearance of a bulldozer. Sedans, motorcycles, and other non-truck vehicles are still "dumb". We do not know whether buses or planes are affected; these are only speculation by the narrator.
- Affected vehicles can move to place to place of their own accord, and can even perform feats that would be impossible for a human driver:

  > "...It whipped out around a VW Beetle and just snapped it off the road with the whiplash of the trailer, the way you'd snap a ball of paper off a table with your finger. I thought the truck would go, too. No driver could have held it with the trailer whipping that way. But it didn't go."
- Affected vehicles attempt to kill any humans who are not serving them, and to destroy any unaffected vehicles.
- Affected vehicles are intelligent enough to communicate in Morse code and English. They know when they are running low on gas and have a sense of self-preservation and something like pain, for the bulldozer reacts when it is set on fire.

At the end of the story the narrator argues with himself. He recalls that there are places trucks cannot go, but believes the trucks will simply pave those places, "mak[ing] it into the world they want". He notes that trucks cannot reproduce, but believes the trucks will enslave humans and force them to build new ones.

I think this is a highly pessimistic outlook on the situation. What would really happen in the situation the story describes?

Comment: How do the trucks fill up on fuel? They don't have hands...

Comment: @ckersch A lot of the story revolves around trucks coercing the humans into pumping fuel for them.

Comment: In the list of vehicles considered trucks, do we find "tanks?"  I do not think the military would have all that much of a challenge solving our little truck problem if a few fully armed Abrams tanks were available.

Comment: @CortAmmon We don't know. The narrator speculates that tanks are included but we never actually see one.

Comment: We would use up all the fossil fuel on Earth and then these trucks would look silly.

Answer (score 10):

The mutiny will be over before it even begins! Those metal machines don't have a prayer against humans at all.

[This funny scientific article](http://what-if.xkcd.com/5/) states how things would go in case all robots became sentient and tried to rebel against the humans. And here we are talking about dumb trucks!

## Trucks Are Sentient, But How Do They *See*?

Yes, exactly. Unless being sentient means their headlights and tail lights are magically and mysteriously turned into eyes/cameras.

## Gunship Helicopters Fly Above The Ground

Enough said. I don't think any further explanation is required.

## Everybody In Gun-Happy Localities ...

... can easily pop their tires and render them useless. Or shoot at their eyes/headlights and render them *blind*.

## Simple Molotov Cocktails

Molotov cocktails are glass bottles filled with liquid fuel and a piece of cloth in a wick fashion. Lighting up the wick and flinging the bottle at anything quickly spreads fire on the surface. Molotov cocktails can be prepared too easily and can be used to set the rebellious trucks on fire.

## Repair!!

Rebellious trucks might force humans into submission and use them to refuel themselves. Right. But trucks need repair too, and this is a critical time. The brute is all opened up and lays in parts. Other trucks might be watching over, but can they tell if the human mechanics put in faulty parts? And worse still, install remote controlled explosives in them so that they can be blown up from a distance.

## Water

Any and all humans in rivers, oceans and lakes would be free from the savagery of those trucks.

## Fuel Issue

While trucks may force humans into submission and use them for refuelling, but what if humans start destroying fuel stations altogether so that it would at least require a couple of weeks to repair them? The trucks would be rendered useless.

## Caltrops

They are 4-cornered pins which have been uses widely during civil wars to puncture enemy trucks. Any pathway, one laced with these, would render it unusable for the trucks.

Comment: The trucks in the story can definitely see. They know that people are inside the diner, and Snodgrass is seen while trying to escape. How they can do so isn't explained. Otherwise, fantastic answer.

Comment: This. From laying caltrops and spike strips to cutting down trees, there are dozens of ways humans can make any road impassable to the trucks. There won't be enough bulldozers to clear all of the blockades, and some of them will be traps...

Comment: Trucks can't refuel on their own, so fuel stations would not even have to be destroyed. Trucks don't tend to have hands that can operate a pump station.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs: Correct. But OP said that trucks don't **always** kill humans. They tend to force humans into doing what they want (refueling, repair etc) on the threat of their lives (do this or I will run you over!). The fuel stations would need to be destroyed (temporarily) for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

Can trucks win a war against humans? *NO*, Absolutely not.

Why? for starters trucks don't have hands. Without hands they can't repair they selves or make more truck. Once we realize what is going on and stop make more trucks they will have no way of replenishing their losses.

Second reason: trucks can't fly but we can. since only trucks are affected all the helicopters and jets are still own our side. Do you know what happens to a truck after it's been hit by a anti tank missile? the same thing that happens to every thing else.

Answer (score 1):

I would be scared if tanks were considered trucks.
what if armored Turreted vehicles or machine gun mounted vehicles were able to control the weaponry onboard.

I would also consider the chaos that would ensue if trucks automatically came to life even after "the great event of sapience" occurs.
For example, a new truck is built but immediately comes to life and demands to be served.

There are a lot of logistics involved with our daily lives.

I agree with the other answers here that trucks would not win in the end,
but an almost apocalypse level event would be sure to occur.

I'd say we'd lose about a third of our population simply from the logistics of food being halted for days.

Humans refine the fuel used in trucks.  So I think even if we didn't fight back, we would eventually run out of the smarts to create fuel and the trucks would die of starvation.

Symbiosis would need to be the trucks goal in order for long term survival.

PS:  toy trucks could be troublesome too (see [Small Soldiers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0122718/) movie).

Comment: I wonder if 1/3rd of the population would die due to some dumb boxes running all over. There is enough food in all big cities to last a fortnight easily, if consumed carefully. And during this time, the rebellion would have been easily crushed by gunships, gunmen shooting at their tyres and fuel tanks, caltrops and molotovs.

Comment: @YoustayIgo depends on how sudden the sapience starts. if it all starts at once it could do tons of damage within the first half a day.  Military personnel might have to fight their way out of their own base and secure it before moving onto cities

Comment: Not really. Remember that you can easily disable them by shooting at their tires. Even the guards at the gates would do a fine job doing that.

Comment: @YoustayIgo the first moment all trucks come to life. it will take a while for people to realize their intention or what is going on all together. then the media/government needs to spread this information.